# Why LLC converter can't work in wide output voltage

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, llc-converter

I've been studying about LLC Converters recently and I've come across a few points that I don't quite understand. Here are my questions:

1.Why can't an LLC Converter achieve a wide output range? Isn't it possible to adjust the output by changing the gain?

2.Some people refer to LLC as a "forward resonant half-bridge." Why is that?

3.Why is the efficiency of an LLC Converter generally higher than that of a PWM Converter?

Comment: These are valid questions but would require quite lengthy answers : ) Please have a look at my [seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20the%20LLC%20Converter.pdf) on control methods of LLC converters, there are a few introductory slides can be of interest. One keyword you can search is *soft switching* which is important to understand why the LLC offers good efficiency compared to *hard-switching* PWM converters.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic answers: -

> *1.Why can't an LLC Converter achieve a wide output range? Isn't it possible to adjust the output by changing the gain?*

You can drive it with a low duty cycle and get lower voltages on the output. To my mind (having designed a fairly powerful one for charging a capacitor efficiently) it had to produce output voltages from 1% up to 100% of full rated output.

> *2.Some people refer to LLC as a "forward resonant half-bridge." Why is that?*

Given that you can use a half bridge or a H-bridge I can't answer this and neither can I tell whom the people are you refer to. For instance, [here's an example using a H-bridge](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-topology-of-the-LLC-resonant-converter_fig2_334739329): -

[image]

> *3.Why is the efficiency of an LLC Converter generally higher than that of a PWM Converter?*

If the converter uses phase shifted PWM (as opposed to regular on-off PWM) then any energy stored in the resonant circuits are kept in the resonant circuits when the PWM is in the idling part of its cycle. Good old-fashioned simple PWM would return the energy stored in the resonant circuits to the main DC supply rail and this would be a significant cause for concern in terms of energy wastage. I mean, it takes a few cycles to build up that energy (at a given duty cycle) and that's what you want for a resonant converter.